# Correct syntax when using variable div ID in jQuery's .load Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery's .load function to load new content into a div of unknown ID. I'm trying to grab its ID from a child element. Starting with an alert returns the parent ID:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('#submitbtn').click(function(){
        var parentId = $('#windowanchor').parent().attr('id');
        alert('ID = ' + parentId);
    });
</script>
```

Good. However, when modifying the code to include the .load function no content is loaded:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('#submitbtn').click(function(){
        var parentId = $('#windowanchor').parent().attr('id');
        $(parentId).load("plug.php?r=calendar&m=edit&id=1");
    });
</script>
```

I suspect that the syntax I've used is wrong (js/jquery rookie). Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID's are unique, so just do

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('#submitbtn').click(function(){
        $('#windowanchor').parent().load("plug.php?r=calendar&m=edit&id=1");
    });
</script>
```

There's no need to get the ID, just to stick it in a selector and get the same element over again !

Comment: This is the cleanest of the answers

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix with `#` in the selector:

```
$("#" + parentId).load("plug.php?r=calendar&m=edit&id=1");
```

However, a cleaner solution would be to just use the reference for the load without obtaining the ID at all:

```
$('#windowanchor').parent().load("plug.php?r=calendar&m=edit&id=1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('#submitbtn').click(function(){
        var parentId = $('#windowanchor').parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+parentId).load("plug.php?r=calendar&m=edit&id=1");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the `#`

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('#submitbtn').click(function(){
        var parentId = $('#windowanchor').parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+parentId).load("plug.php?r=calendar&m=edit&id=1");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend a `#` to the `parentId` so that the selector works properly.

```
var parentId = '#' + $('#windowanchor').parent().attr('id');
$(parentId).load("plug.php?r=calendar&m=edit&id=1");
```

This way, if the `id` attribute of the `#windowanchor`'s parent is `main`, the selector becomes `#main`.

Although, [adeneo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22992808/2038227) is ideal; rather than fetching the parent's ID and running another jQuery selector, simply calling the `.load()` method directly on `$('#windowanchor').parent()` is more efficient.